# Fragment lifecycle in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, lifecycle, drawer

what happens to the fragments in navigation drawer?
when you switch between them from the navigation drawer menu are they destroyed? or do they pause?

I need to understand exactly the lifecycle of a fragment after inflated into the main activity of a navigation drawer type project. when I switch from one menu's item to another, what happens to the already existing fragment? does it destroy or pause? fragments are recreated every time?

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to a new fragment and replace the existing fragment, the lifecycle methods of the old fragment, such as onPause(), onStop(), and onDestroyView().
And then the fragment is removed from the view hierarchy.
If you navigate back to the previous fragment, it will be recreated, and its lifecycle methods will be called again. This means that the onCreateView() and all the other methods would be called again.